# Where is the mistake in the instance?

Tags: php, oop

**Before I ask about problem, I read the suggested link, but it didn't help me.**

My problem is when I try to **instance a class**.

The error is:

> Notice: Undefined variable: userCore in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/proyecto_cice/app/web/controller/controllerFormUser.php
>   on line 74

**I know the meaning of this notice, so I use the function class_exists() and I give me true. I used this function, because my first idea was I make a mistake in the class, but it isn't the problem.**

**I declare this object in load.php file, because I need it in others files too.**

**I understand the error, but I don't find it.** If you can help, I'll be grateful.

The code in the main file where I try instance the class:

```
<?php
require '../load.php';

function signup($form){
    if( $form['pass']== $form['repass'] ){

    $exists = $userCore->find_mail( filter_project_form() );

    if($exists==''){
        $isCorrect = ($userCore->insert_user( filter_project_form() ));
            if($isCorrect){echo 'correct';}
    }
    else{
        echo "The user exists now";
    }
  }
  else{
    echo 'The passwords must be identical';
  }
}
?>
```

And the file 'load.php' contains:

```
<?php
//CONFIG
require 'config.php';
require 'constants.php';

//CORE
require 'core/ddbb.php';
require 'core/user.php';
</code>
//CLASS MODEL
require 'model/class_user.php';

//CONTROLLER
require 'controller/controllerUser.php';

//INSTANCIA
$userCore = new User_core();
```

And the file core/user.php is:

```
<?php
class User_core extends DDBB_core{
    function find_mail($form){
       $sql = "SELECT email FROM user WHERE email='".$form['mail']."'";
        return $this->executeSelectQuery($sql);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The local variable `$userCore` is used in function `signup()` but it is not initialized anywhere. Read about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Do the down-voters care to explain their votes to the OP?

Comment: @George Nobody is obliged to do so.

Comment: @deceze I'm aware, but it'd be nice for the OP if they had some reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$userCore` is not available in your function, as it is defined in the outer scope. You need to make it available:

```
[...] 

function signup($form){
    global $userCore;

    [...]
```

By the way, doing things like this is considered bad practice and it goes against the OOP principles. It would be better if you made `siginup` a method of the `UserCore` class, or used some kind of rendering utility class for this, where you instead pass the instance of `UserCore` as one of the arguments to the function instead.